# What to do with hand luggage in airports?

Tags: air-travel, airports, hand-luggage

*I'm looking for general advice here, not specific to any airports.*

Many times in airports it's a hassle to drag around/carry hang luggage into the shops and places you're visiting. Especially when signs saying that bags can't be taken into the shops.

This leads to a difficult situation. How should you deal with hand luggage in these cases? Is the only option to not go into the shop, or maybe leaving the hand luggage at the counter?

Comment: If they don't allow carry-ons in the shops in the airport they should provide a place to store it.

Comment: Are you travelling by yourself or with others?  Not to be snarky, but often leaving one person with the luggage is the simplest solution

Comment: Forever alone :)

Comment: Can you name an airport where you have experienced this issue? If airports shops did not allow people with bags to enter then I would have thought they would get very little business! As for myself I tend to put my hand baggage in a trolley.

Comment: It was in Tenerife

Comment: Is lounge access an option? Either via paying for it, or getting it through your airline (frequent traveller, premium cabin etc)? Many, but by no means all lounges offer to look after your bags while you go shopping

Comment: just walk into the shop with your bag, and leave if they complain

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best advice is to bring as little "stuff" as possible. If you think about all the stuff you're bringing, you could categorize it like this:

- I will definitely need it in the airport or on the plane (Eg passport, money)
- It will make me more comfortable in the airport or on the plane (eg pillow, book)
- If it were lost, stolen, delayed or damaged my trip would be pointless or ruined (eg laptop)

  ---
- If I check it I will have to pay a baggage fee or wait for it to come out on the belt

Try to restrict yourself to items "above the line". Now what you're dealing with in the stores, the bathroom, at security and so on is a large purse or a small backpack and not something on wheels that a store might be likely to ban.

Of course if you're travelling with another person, it's such a luxury to leave your stuff with them while you pop off to do something.

Many business lounges have small lockers - you can't get a rollaboard in them, but you can get a backpack in, and I have used that to stash my carryon while I spent a layover exploring a city. It's overkill for wanting to go shopping, but something to keep in mind if you have a long time to spend in an airport. (I believe they're designed for you to put your stuff in while you shower, or to simplify wandering around the lounge getting food, drink, and reading material without wanting to drag all your stuff around.)

Comment: Given the current sprawl of the low cost airlines a lot of people don't have checked bags.  On top of this even if you do have checked bags you might need a change of clothes for a day or 2 just in case you bags don't make it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. THere are some good guidelines. However, there's also, in addition to Karlson's suggestion, the possibility of needing the extra weight in the case of longer stays. I guess having to drag it around (or storing it as you mentioned) is the only option then.

Answer (score 1):

Some airports have lockers or storage rooms where you can store bags, but there is usually a charge for them.  (I was surprised that airports still have these, but I've used them, for example, when I had multiple hours between flights in Shanghai, I stored my bags at the baggage storage counter and rode the Maglev just for fun.)

If you have access to an airport lounge, those often have complimentary baggage storage rooms.